# Authenticate to Azure DevOps Services with MSAL-Angular

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-ad-msal, azure-devops-rest-api, msal.js

I try configure my application to connect in the Azure DevOps Services by oauth. My application is in Angular and I think I can use the MSAL-Angular .

But the sample configuration setting the protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']); and I like to configure to Azure DevOps Service with the scope vso.project vso.work_full

I create well the application and by Postman I simulate get the Token and use. But in my application the MSAL isn't work.

I tried :

```js
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read', 'vso.project', 'vso.work_full']);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['user.read', 'vso.project', 'vso.work_full']
    },
    loginFailedRoute: '/login-failed'
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    DetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But the MSAL not connect in the application.

I like to use https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me instand of https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Comment: What error did you get? You can check the documentation below: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#microsoft-authentication-library-for-javascript-msaljs and the sample https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/JavascriptWebAppSample to see whether they can help you.

Comment: I try use that links, but the Azure AD has different configuration than DevOps Application.

Comment: Could you elaborate that?

Comment: I had a wrong perception of MSAL.JS I tried to use it like graphMS to DevOps but that not work. So I study the Oauth Process [DevOps Oauth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#:~:text=Azure%20DevOps%20Services%20uses%20the,ID%20from%20Azure%20DevOps%20Services) and implement a specific process manually.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have more errors. i change my architecture making a manually OAUTH and not use MSAL anymore trying authenticate in DevOps Azure.